# fsck on an ext2 filesystem. “…directory corrupted”

Tags: linux, filesystems, fsck, ext2

**UPDATE: Fixed! The final directory entry in a block must point to the end of the block that it is in (I did this by adjusting the length of the final block to span the remainder of the block).**

I'm working on a program that can export ext2 filesystem images. fsck is my best friend and worst enemy right now - as it's both super helpful in finding out what's going wrong, and also super difficult to find online resources about specific issues...

My current issue (which Google is yielding nothing on) is:

```
Directory inode 2, block #0, offset 24: directory corrupted
```

This is the extent of the information given to me from fsck. Can any kind soul advise as to what exactly this is trying to tell me? What exactly is corrupted? Many thanks.

Does the 'offset 24' refer to the 24th byte in Inode 2? Datablock 0? Either way, I can't seem to find the answer by comparing the before/afters of a fsck.